# Creating simple calculator

Tags: javascript, function, loops, calculator

I am trying to solve a problem given to me and it involves using basic loops, functions and conditions. I have been given the below:

```
// TODO: complete program

console.log(calculate(4, "+", 6));  // Must show 10
console.log(calculate(4, "-", 6));  // Must show -2
console.log(calculate(2, "*", 0));  // Must show 0
console.log(calculate(12, "/", 0)); // Must show Infinity
```

and this is my attempt (not working of course). Can anyone give me a nudge of a pointer as to what I am doing wrong?

```js
function calculate(n1, n2, n3) {
  let calc
  if n2 = "+" {
    (calc = +)
  };
  else if n2 = "-" {
    (calc = -)
  };
  else if n2 = "*" {
    (calc = * )
  };
  else {
    (calc = /)
  };
  let acalc = (n1 + n2 + n3);
  return acalc;
}

console.log(calculate(4, "+", 6)); // Must show 10
console.log(calculate(4, "-", 6)); // Must show -2
console.log(calculate(2, "*", 0)); // Must show 0
console.log(calculate(12, "/", 0)); // Must show Infinity
```

Comment: What is the unexpected result you are experiencing

Comment: The error I am getting is "Unexpected identifier" and nothing showing in console.

Comment: When you are comparing n2, you need to use `===`. Currently you are using the assignment operator `=`. You are also missing parenthesis around your `if` statements

Comment: `(calc = /)` or any of those listed in the ifs are not valid expressions

Comment: There are a lot of basic language and syntax issues - semicolons on if/else statements, using assignment operator in place of equality checking (`=` vs `==` or `===`), among other things.

Comment: Thank you Vincent, really helpful tips will give it a go.

Comment: Thanks all, really helpful. :)

Comment: Can anyone help - why has my question been downvoted?? I am asking as trying to learn, is Stackoverflow only for more advanced questions?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set variables equal to operators. Your `if` blocks should look like this instead:

```
if (n2 == "+") {
  return parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n3);
};
```

Use `parseInt` if you are passing in strings instead of numbers

Comment: Also the semi-colons after if blocks are completely unnecessary and also syntax errors if trying to do `else`...

Also comparison operators are `==` not `=`...

Also parens around the assignments aren't necessary either unless you're performing complex calculations...

Comment: Yes, OP should probably follow a tutorial to get familiar with the syntax before doing more complicated things https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp

Comment: Thanks @Fueled By Coffee
I am in the process of learning, hence this exercise Sacha.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the input given in the n2 parameter and return the calculation directly. Also you had some issues with () in your code.

```
function calculate(n1, n2, n3) {
if (n2 == "+") {
    return n1 + n3;
} else if (n2 == "-") {
    return n1 - n3;
} else if (n2 == "*") {
    return n1 * n3;
} else {
    return n1 / n3;
}; };
```

Comment: Nice that is probably what I needed to do in the first place, thanks!